# Is their a better way of creating list of list instead of checking line by line

Tags: python

```py
inp_str1 = 'why are you still using cycle. Happy ride.'

inp_str2 = 'happy,cycle'
```

output:

```py
['happy', [Happy ride], 'cycle', ['why are you still using cycle']]
```

Got the expected answer, but `inp_str1` is searched 'n' number of times. n = number of words in `inp_str2`.

```py
inp_str1 = 'why are you still using cycle. Happy ride.'
inp_str2 = 'happy,cycle'

.....

slist = inp_str2.split(',')

    for word in slist:    
        out.append(word)
        for line in inp_str1.split('.'):         
            if (word in line):
                temp.append(line.strip())
            else:
                pass
        out.append(temp); temp=[]

;
   .....
print(out)
```

How to get the same result in a single iteration. 
Search a string(`inp_str1`) for all the words in (`inp_str2`) only once and generate the above output.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is you're doing the first cycle over search words, not over lines. If you want to check every sentence in inp_str1 only once, you should cycle over it first. Also, I don't quite understand why are you using a list instead of a dict for final output, can you please add what result you're expecting.

With dict output the code will look something like this:

```
out = {search_word: [] for search_word in slist}
for line in inp_str1.split('.'):
    for word in slist:
        if word in line.lower():
            out[word].append(line)
```

It will generate the following output:

```
{'happy': [' Happy ride'], 'cycle': ['why are you still using cycle']}
```

So you will hit every sentence in search string one time and every word in inp_str1 once for every string in str_2.

If you're sure you need list as output, you just need to copy your appending commands in a new inner cycle.

Hope it'll help